# How to show the flow termination in Sequence Diagram

Tags: uml, software-design, sequence-diagram, plantuml

Basically, I'd like to depict the below logic in a Sequence Diagram:

```
if (ShopIsOpen) {
  if (AccessTokenIsExpired) {
    if (RefreshTokenInExpired) {
      return "Not Authorized";
    }
    IdentityServer.RequestAccessTokenByRefreshToken();
    return Resource.RequestResourceByAccessToken();
  }
} else {
  return "Shop is closed";
}
```

I've come up with the below diagram, but I am not sure if it is correct.
Mainly, I am not sure if `break` in the diagram correctly communicates the intention of termination of flow: does it imply jumping out of the outer `opt` or the outer `alt`?

Any help is much appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Looks ok. However, _graphical programming_ isn't the best to do. Use SDs of overviews how objects collaborate. Eventually use notes for programming hints. But leave the coding to the coders.

Comment: @qwerty_so Yes correct; that was just an example.

Comment: Set aside that the question title is something else you ask in the text: if you get a definition of the break behavior, then what do you think the readers of such a document would understand? They would probably have the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

The `break fragment` leaves the immediately enclosing fragment. In your case that would be the `opt fragment`. So, it is not correct. Why don’t you use nested `alt fragments`?

Some additional remarks: The reply to a synchronous message is shown with a dashed line and the returned value is shown with a leading colon (and the name of the original message, but I think it is obvious here anyway).

Comment: How would you depict the function return in a nested `alt fragment`?